# why tensorflow missing the only attribute "tf.strided_slice"?

Tags: tensorflow, slice, stride

I tested many functions in `tensorflow` module, and the `tf.strided_slice` is the only attribute missing...

Could someone please tell me what's going on?? thanks!

the screenshot is at the following link.

[screenshot of the missing attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDqPl.png)

Comment: sorry. there two typoes... one is in title. It should be tf.strided_slice...
one is in the screenshot, I just tested the tf.strided_slice. The error is still: 'module' object has no attribute 'strided_slice'

Comment: You could [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40343941/edit) the question to fix the typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called [`strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#strided_slice), not `stride_slice`. Note the "d" before the underscore.

Also note if the TensorFlow version is recent enough by checking `tf.__version__`. The most recent stable branch (as of 2017 Feb) is 0.12. If the version is older than 0.10, please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to stackoverlow:(
 I just updated a screenshot. I couldn't figure out what's going on...

Comment: I just reinstall the tensorflow. And the problem is solved. Thank you very much anyway^_^

Comment: I'm using anaconda. I made 3.5 and 2.7 virtual environments and conda installed tensorflow. Neither one has strided_slice. Reinstall didn't work.

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos Could you print `tf.__version__` to check which TensorFlow version you have installed?

Comment: @kennytm I realized that I had the wrong version of Tensorflow installed! I had 0.10 and when I upgraded to 0.12 the issue went away. A new issue arose about missing arguments, apparently the function signature changed from 0.xx to 1.xx. The error about missing arguments has a few posts here on Stackoverflow. I think the tutorial needs a Note: [explain what code to use with each version]. I want to submit a PR. Maybe you could if you know alot about the package. You seem to have understood what my problem was immediately!